# Load testing of protected api using wrk?

Tags: wrk

I am learning [wrk](https://github.com/wg/wrk). I have an api /count over POST that is protected by basic auth. How to pass the basic auth credentials for wrk. Right now, I am using the header option to pass the "Authorzation" to carry the base64 encoded credential. Is there a way to pass the credential as user & password? It would be useful to share within my team.